# CSS alternative to to HTML <center>

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to center a bunch of elements for a little while now. When I came across the `<center>` element, I got really excited when I tried it because it worked exactly how I wanted it to. But then I noticed that it is deprecated with HTML5. When I looked into it, everything said to just use CSS to center your text but I am not only trying to center text but a few different elements.

```
 <div class="col-lg-1 col-mid-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
   <center>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary circle" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
       <img src="assets/img/img.png">
     </button>
     <p>Some Text</p>
   </center>
 </div>
```

Everything I read tells me to use:

```
 margin:0px auto;
```

But this does not have the same affect as the `<center>` element does.

Comment: Actually, it's obsolete in HTML5, not just deprecated.

Comment: an example - margin:0px auto; width:200px;

Comment: The element is still supported in major browsers, for back compatibility. But it's obsolete, like Rob said, because HTML's focus is to represent document **structure**, while styling is what CSS is for. You may find `<center>` still works and very handy, but I suggest you put some effort in learning CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `text-align:center;` but all the children elements needs to have `display: inline` or `display:inline-block`

Example in your case:

```
.col-lg-1 { text-align:center; }
p, button { display:inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have the outer container (as long as its block level) set to margin:auto and then text-align:center to cover any inline elements.

```
div{
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```