# Content does not center on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

Soooo, basically, title. I've tried a bunch of different solutions, none of which seem to solve my problem. The website itself is centered when the content is small enough, but if it exceeds the device's size, it stretches out to the right. Here's what the code for the site looks like:

```css
body {
  background: url("fireworkplusothers-20.jpg");
  color: black;
}


/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: white;
}


/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: grey;
}


/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: grey;
}


/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <p style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Courier New', monospace;"><b> <a href=photo.html>+</a> &nbsp; <a href=tooth.html>+</a> &nbsp; <a href=perfect.html>+</a> &nbsp; <a href=nn1.html>+</a> &nbsp; <a href=nn1.html>+</a> &nbsp; <a href=about.html>+</a></b></p>

  <img src="SP_ribcage.png" alt="idk" class="center" width="1000" height="666.66">

</center>
```

Help appreciated, this is my first website :D

Comment: Oops, meant stretches out to the right

Comment: You've posted the HTML twice. You can click the Edit link and update your question.

Comment: Please note that the `<center>` tag is now deprecated, and browsers may phase out support for it soon. https://caniuse.com/?search=center [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) **[Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443252/css-alternative-to-to-html-center)**

Comment: Where do you set the width of body?

Answer (score 0):

This is because 1000px is over the devices screen size, so it is overflowing.

One way to fix this is with `max-width` in CSS. By setting the `max-width` to `1000px`, and setting `width` to `100%`, if the screen size is over `1000px`, the width will be set to `1000px`, otherwise it will be set to the screen size.

Example:

```css
img {
  max-width: 6000px; /* absurdly large picture width that won't fit on many screens */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080">
```

Learn more about:

[`max-width` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

[`width` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)